# Can adults overcome rhotacism?

Tags: research, speech, speech-therapy, speech-pathology

According to Wikipedia:

> In medical contexts, rhotacism is the inability or difficulty in
>   pronouncing the sound **r**.

Do adults have a significantly high chance of overcoming rhotacism, if putting in enough effort? Is there any scientific research around the subject?

Comment: I'm a speech pathologist, but I don't know of any specific research on prognosis as an adult. What I can say, though, is that the recommendation is that if traditional speech therapy methods have been unsuccessful, there is some research that less traditional methods (ultrasound is a good example) can sometimes help. Also, I have never heard the term "rhotacism." In teens and adults who don't have a typical r sound, most US SLPs would call this a "residual r error," in the absence of any structural or functional problem.

Comment: @Katherine You seem knowledgeable on the subject, could you cite some of the research and write up an answer? Thanks!